# What to do if I inject a IDisposable transient component into a controller (Castle Windsor)

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Basically, should I call .Dispose() myself? Because from what I've read, Windsor won't do that for me. I'm new to IoC and this is slightly confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to KK [mvc3 tutorial](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx).
WindsorControllerFactory acts as composition root: factory takes care to create and release controller via container. Since "Windsor is best of breed, mature Inversion of Control container available for .NET" takes care to release all components starting from the root of the object graph... as long as you properly set up the container...
Read also this post about [windosr releasing policy](http://kozmic.pl/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/).